# How does Java's SecureRandom know which implementation of NativePRNG is available on the system?

Tags: java, cryptography, jvm

using java.security.SecureRandom

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

will, according to

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

produce random bytes by using the system implementation of NativePRNG.

How does Java runtime know where on the system this implementation it is? On GNU/Linux it is usually /dev/random but this is not the case on Windows. Is there a config file somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following information can be gleaned from inspecting the sourcecode of SecureRandom.java, which ships in the **src.zip** with the JDK.

Use the source, Luke!

> How does Java runtime know where on the system this implementation it is?

That's a platform-specific part of the JDK.

`SecureRandom` enumerates the registered `java.security.Provider` instances, looking for one providing a `java.security.Provider.Service` of the type `"SecureRandom"`.
The JDK generally ships with an internal default security provider, which implements that in a platform-specific manner.

If none can be found it falls back to pure java SHA1PRNG.